# How to select parent element of a tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add  `green_bg` class when a radio is selected on the parent div

```
<div class="content red_bg">       
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">    
</div>
<div class="content  red_bg">
<input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
</div>
<div class="content  red_bg">
<input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
</div>
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
        $(".content").removeClass("red_bg").addClass("green_bg");
            });

});
```

But when i select a radio, all the background turns green Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select just the parent `.content` of the clicked button:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
  $(this).closest(".content").removeClass("red_bg").addClass("green_bg");
});
```

or, if you also want to *reset* all of the others:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
  $('.content').addClass('red_bg').removeClass('green_bg');
  $(this).closest(".content").removeClass("red_bg").addClass("green_bg");
});
```

Example:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
  $('.content').addClass('red_bg').removeClass('green_bg');
  $(this).closest(".content").removeClass("red_bg").addClass("green_bg");
});
```

```css
.green_bg {
  background-color: green;
 }

.red_bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content red_bg">       
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">    
</div>
<div class="content  red_bg">
<input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
</div>
<div class="content  red_bg">
<input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
    <input type="radio" name="answerkey" id="ankeya2" value="option2">
</div>
```

Comment: What about a span tag inside the `<div class="content  red_bg">` how change the background of that?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.content').find('span').addClass(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
        $(this).parent().removeClass("red_bg").addClass("green_bg");
    });
});
```